# Should this question have been closed for mentioning piracy?

Tags: discussion, closing, specific-question

After answering [this](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/q/371320/250180) question with a good answer that got 23 upvotes, it has now been closed because the asker mentioned that it was a pirated game.

The question was a pretty good question though, and the answer doesn't change with the fact that the game was pirated. Either way, I think that there should be an unclosed version of this question.

Here are some possible resolutions to the problem:

1. Reopen the question and edit it so it doesn't mention piracy.
2. Add a new question about the same topic that doesn't mention piracy.
3. Do nothing, the closed question already provides an answer. (I don't recommend this one because people will not be able to pitch in their own answer to this question.)

What is your take on this?

Comment: Related: https://gaming.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/10517/we-shouldnt-help-users-run-pirated-software

Comment: Ironically, [the duplicate of that one](https://gaming.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/7546/when-does-a-question-support-piracy-and-pirated-games) may be more related here

Comment: The question shouldn't have been closed in the first place as per [When does a question “support piracy and pirated games”?](https://gaming.meta.stackexchange.com/q/7546/4797) "closing a question strictly because the asker admits (or implies) the use of an illegal copy, is a misuse of close votes."

Comment: Kinds of reminds me of [a similar situation](https://meta.askubuntu.com/q/17404/612877) years ago on Ask Ubuntu.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The thread [When does a question "support piracy and pirated games"?](https://gaming.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/7546/when-does-a-question-support-piracy-and-pirated-games), addressing exactly this problem, has an accepted answer. The closing of the question you mention goes against this and the three out of four other upvoted answers, and therefor the general consensus.

- The problem posed in the question you link is independent of the legitimacy of the ownership of the game.
- The problem and answer are useful to other users.
- The problem and answering of it do not stimulate piracy.

Solution: **remove the comment about the game being pirated, and reopen it.**