# Why is this "unreleased content", when it actually isn't?

Tags: support

https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/156633/how-do-i-get-the-legendary-pokemon-diancie

Why was this closed?

Ironically, even though some here thought it was "unreleased", at the time of the posting, the Pokemon was obtainable for JP residents (gaming.SE is NOT a primarily American website, it is for all cultures and from different countries).  The Pokemon itself wasn't just a screenshot, because the files for Diancie ALREADY EXIST within Pokemon X & Y cartridges.

It's not "unreleased", because other people from across the globe already have access to them, yet some people voted to close because it "wasn't" out yet when it clearly already was.

Take a look at this video.  If the content is supposedly "unreleased", how would this user have gotten it if he wasn't a Game Freak/Nintendo employee?

Comment: I can't find any release date related to it, could you link to one?

Comment: If the pokemon has ALREADY existed in the game files since day one, how can you close a question on the basis of "unreleased content", since it is now sitting on almost 1,000,000 pokemon xy cartridges and counting

Comment: For example, I would understand if someone asked a question about "when is hl3 coming out" because it hasn't existed as a file at any point yet, or has no official release yet.  The Pokemon however has existed within the game and there are clearly plenty of Youtubers who already have gotten the Pokemon.

Comment: [You might want to read one of the most recent takes on unreleased content](http://meta.gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/8511/is-this-question-off-topic-because-of-the-release-date). One of the highly upvoted comments mentions that datamining ("but the file existsssss") is a bad argument to make on a site focused on playing the games. [When is a game publicly available](http://meta.gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/5539/when-is-a-game-publicly-available) agrees that there should be a playable version not limited to the press or employees. I have to mention I know nothing about pokemon, tho.

Comment: @slowpoke are you ignoring the "through legitimate means" portion of how the close reason is phrased? (I.E., we generally consider mods to current consoles for this sort of thing verboten.) I don't know enough about this situation to say whether it applies, but your total failure to address it is, at least a little, telling.

Comment: What do you mean legitimate?  Do we ban users asking questions about downloading Pokemon?  Some users will, instead of spending a month's time on the game just to get a fully trained EV/IV pokmeon, will spawn them in.  The game recognizes it as being "legal", and as such, is their really a problem? Why do users have to live up to some lofty expectations that they shouldn't have?

Comment: @Slowpoke cheating in multiplayer games is verboten here as well.

Comment: Can you prove it exists in files?  You use that as a justification, but have absolutely no proof to back it up whatsoever.  You asked the question directly after it had been announced.  You arguing that it exists was done in bad faith, in an attempt to keep your question.

Comment: Diancie along with the other Gen6 event distribution legendaries, are all effectively free on-disk DLC. **Unreleased** free on-disk DLC. Despite Nintendo being Nintendo and pointlessly keeping a lid on things, the Pokemon community has known just about everything about every legendary because hackers have found ways around the otherwise gated content. Take for example the [Azure Flute](http://bulbapedia.bulbagarden.net/wiki/Azure_Flute). Designed as the way the players were supposed to obtain Arceus, it was **never released**.

Comment: So, while this Wonder Card may be how Diancie was *meant* to be received, it may never see the light of day. *We don't know yet how Nintendo will officially release this pokemon to the players*. While it is there, on the cartride, we do not know the means by which we will receive it until nintendo releases it.

Comment: What defines cheating @badp? If a player creates a Pokemon with perfect IV/EVs with the right nature and is shiny, is that cheating?

Comment: @slowpoke how is it *not* cheating?

Comment: Let me give a clearer example. Some Pokemon cannot learn specific moves. For example, a Charizard can obviously not learn Hydro Cannon, or have stats to 999.  If you find a player in-game that has a Charizard with Hydro Cannon and stats to 999, yes that player hacked the Pokemon and cheated the game, because a normal player without any tools besides the game could not create that himself. However, if a player has a Pokemon that's Shiny, has perfect IV's, and perfect EVs, and got them through hacked Pokemon, that's no different than a user who spent the time soft-resetting for the same Pokemon.

Comment: This is really a question of whether someone subscribes to moral legitness or to programmatic legitness: hacking an item to get an event generates a pokemon which is programmatically legit, but moralists would argue that the pokemon should never have existed.

Comment: Are you seriously trying to justify your "unreleased content" question with "It's not cheating!!"? We don't support *any* form of multiplayer-relevant cheating, no matter if it "could be valid". We don't allow questions on how to hack in stats, and neither do we allow hacking in pokemon. We have *very* few exceptions.

Answer (score 10):

Let's start with the basic essence of how closure works. One of the reasons we have closure is because a question cannot be reasonably answered in its current state. In some cases this is because the question is poorly written, but for this particular case it's because the proper information isn't distributed in the proper channels, if it is distributed at all. That's why we have the unreleased content close reason - it's unreasonable to expect us to properly answer these kinds of questions because they exist outside the scope of what our actual expertise deals with.

Let me quote you explicitly from a comment on the only answer, which states that it's unknown:

> I'll mark this as accepted for now, **since there's no way to figure out how to get it**, but when they do announce it, do you mind updating your answer?

This statement I bolded is everything saying this question shouldn't have been asked yet. And you yourself acknowledge this. It trumps the matter of "it's in the game files" because you, me, everyone, we *all* know it isn't out yet. Traces of knowledge of the existence of not just Diancie but all the event legendaries has been present since December, if you knew where to look. We're not the place to look for this, though.

There's no benefit to the community to keep the question around right now. Diancie still isn't publicly released since the time the question was asked, and so far people peg it at July. The important thing is that July isn't right now, and [it's not our job to be a news site to keep people up to date on things](https://gaming.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/7286/what-is-considered-future-here/7290#7290), which is the only thing that having the question around can serve right now.